# how to show placeholder/watermark in table filter column

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

[image: show placeholder in it]

I have added table from data control on my .jsf page with filterable option enabled.
now i can filter data from my table, but i want to show some placeholder like "search here".
how can i show placeholder in search column box?

```
<af:column
    sortProperty="#{bindings.TblProgView12.hints.ProgId.name}"
    filterable="true" sortable="true" headerText="Program ID"
    align="center" id="c1" width="51">
    <af:inputText value="#{row.bindings.ProgId.inputValue}"
        label="#{bindings.TblProgView12.hints.ProgId.label}"
        required="#{bindings.TblProgView12.hints.ProgId.mandatory}"
        columns="#{bindings.TblProgView12.hints.ProgId.displayWidth}"
        maximumLength="#{bindings.TblProgView12.hints.ProgId.precision}"
        shortDesc="#{bindings.TblProgView12.hints.ProgId.tooltip}" id="it1"
        readOnly="true" contentStyle='text-align:center'>
        <f:validator binding="#{row.bindings.ProgId.validator}" />
    </af:inputText>
</af:column>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to create a specific search form for your table with a notice and title is to use the af:query component that comes with your iterator.(Drag&Drop your iterator from datacontrol and select query, read more here : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/apirefs.1111/e12419/tagdoc/af_query.html)

However as you ask specificaly ***how can i show placeholder in search column box?***

You can add a **filter** facet to your column to modify the filter component like follow :

```
<af:column sortProperty="#{bindings.TblProgView12.hints.ProgId.name}"
       filterable="true" sortable="true"
       headerText="Program ID" align="center"
       id="c1" width="51">
       <f:facet name="filter">
            <af:inputText value="#{vs.filterCriteria.ProgId}" 
                  placeholder="SEARCH HERE" id="id4">
            </af:inputText>
        </f:facet>
    <af:inputText value="#{row.bindings.ProgId.inputValue}"
                  label="#{bindings.TblProgView12.hints.ProgId.label}"
                  required="#{bindings.TblProgView12.hints.ProgId.mandatory}"
                  columns="#{bindings.TblProgView12.hints.ProgId.displayWidth}"
                  maximumLength="#{bindings.TblProgView12.hints.ProgId.precision}"
                  shortDesc="#{bindings.TblProgView12.hints.ProgId.tooltip}"
                  id="it1" readOnly="true"
                  contentStyle='text-align:center'>
        <f:validator binding="#{row.bindings.ProgId.validator}"/>
    </af:inputText>
</af:column>
```

Comment: Nice solution so far, but I think `placeholder=` instead of `shortDesc=` would be the attribute preferred by the OP.

Comment: You are right @Selaron, for more clarification shortDesc can be used to show HINT: on focus, but to show placeholder we will use placeholder attribute.

Comment: @AhmadMirza my edit to the answer was just accepted.